# How to insert the data from the object into the jTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have an object `Person`. This object is in a List.
Now I want to insert the data **vorname**, **nachname** and **alter** into the `jTable`.

How can I do this?

```
public MainForm() {
    eintragenButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            personList = personAnlegen.PersonAnlegen(
                    textFieldVorname.getText(),
                    textFieldNachname.getText(),
                    textFieldAlter.getText()
            );

            String[] spaltenueberschrift = {"Vorname", "Nachname","Alter"};
            String[][] inhalt;

            for (int i = 0; i < personList.size(); i++) {
                inhalt[i][i] = personList.get(0).getVorname(), personList.get(0).getNachname(), personList.get(0).getAlter();
            }

            tablePersonen = new JTable();
            scrollPane.setViewportView(tablePersonen);

            DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(
                    inhalt,
                    spaltenueberschrift
            );
            tablePersonen.setModel(tableModel);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have I a object "Person" this object is in a List

Basically the `List` needs to be part of a custom `TableModel`.

You need to create a custom `TableModel` for your `Person` object.

Check out [Row Table Model](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/21/row-table-model/) for a step by step approach on how you can do this.

The link also shows how to make a more generic `TableModel` so you can reuse common code.

Answer (score 0):

"Versuch dies" try this

```
JTable tablePersonen = new JTable(inhalt, spaltenueberschrift);
```

> JTable(Object[][] rowData, Object[] columnNames)

openbooks(in german): http://openbook.rheinwerk-verlag.de/javainsel9/javainsel_19_019.htm

Comment: Yes, but how can I get the data from the object "Person" to the array und then into the jTable

Answer (score -1):

You should make new AbstractTableModel()
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data

```
    personList = personAnlegen.PersonAnlegen(
            textFieldVorname.getText(),
            textFieldNachname.getText(),
            textFieldAlter.getText()
    );

    String[] spaltenueberschrift = {"Vorname", "Nachname","Alter"};
    String[][] inhalt;

    for (int i = 0; i < personList.size(); i++) {
        inhalt[i][i] = personList.get(0).getVorname(), personList.get(0).getNachname(), personList.get(0).getAlter();
    }

    tablePersonen = new JTable();
    scrollPane.setViewportView(tablePersonen);

    tablePersonen.setModel(new AbstractTableModel() {

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return inhalt[rowIndex][columnIndex];
        }


        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return inhalt.length;
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {

            return spaltenueberschrift.length;
        }

        public String getColumnName(int col) {
            return spaltenueberschrift[col];
        }
    });
```

Comment: (1-) the data to display in the table should be fully contained in the TableModel. Please follow my link to understand how this is done.